# NSData to NSString random characters

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

when i log the vaule for `responseString` below, it always has random characters - is that a php issue or an ios issue?

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

NSString *success = @"200200";
[success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)responseString.length);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)success.length);
//responseString.length should = success.length but doesn't :(
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you're getting at here. This makes little sense as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[responseData bytes]` just returns a pointer to the bytes in `responseData`, **without** NUL-termination. Therefore you get random characters in `responseString`.

For correct conversion, use

```
NSString *responseString = [NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: awesome! that fixed everything! thank you

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable, so this line doesn't do anything:

```
[success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Did you mean to assign that to something?

```
NSData *successData = [success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```